# Using re.compile with a list of variables to get a value using PyMongo

Tags: python, regex, mongodb, pymongo

Currently I have a list of items like so:

```
list_Of_Packages = ['windows', 'python', ...]

t                       = r'.*|.*'.join(list_Of_Packages)
r                       = re.compile(t)
```

From this I am getting the error

```
sre_constant.error: Multiple repeat
```

Why am I getting this error, and what is the best practice approach for querying a large number of values in a Mongo database with Regexes?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `list_Of_Package_Names` or `list_Of_Packages`? Why use `.*` at all? I guess some of the packages start with `*`, `?` or `+`. Use `r'|'.join([re.escape(x) for x in list_Of_Packages])`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew As the values of the Mongo database are in different formats, and there is a large number of them, I wanted to match entries that  contained the same values as the list. I was using '.*' to get all values that contained that string at some point. And I meant list_Of_Packages sorry

Comment: So, tried `r'|'.join([re.escape(x) for x in list_Of_Packages])`?